# How do I margin a div as much as another?

Tags: html, css, margin, overlap

I want my holder to not to overlap with my navbar, can I set holder's margin-top to be exactly as much as my navbar without putting in numbers?

Here's the html,

```css
#navbar {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: grey;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
#holder {
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: #F7F4EE;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul ID="navbar">
    <li><a class="active" href="home.html">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="news.html">News</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="holder">
  <header>""</header>
  <div id="body">""</div>
  <footer>""</footer>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: How should your output look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to use this

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

and for addition, you can use this

```
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
```

**remember to put it on css** so it become like this

```
#navbar {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: grey;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#holder {
    min-height: 100%;
    background-color: #F7F4EE;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
#navbar {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: grey;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%;
    z-index:999;
}
#navbar li {
    list-style:none;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right:10px;
}
#holder {
    min-height: 100%;
    background-color: #F7F4EE;
    position: relative;
    padding-top:50px;
}
</style>

<div id="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li><a class="active" href="home.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="news.html">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="holder">
  <header>""</header>
  <div id="body">""</div>
  <footer>""</footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `JQuery`, you just calculate `height` of navbar, and that height will be `margin top` of `holder`:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var navbar = $('.navbar').height(); 
  console.log(navbar);
  $('#holder').css({
    marginTop: navbar
  })
})
```

```css
.navbar {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: grey;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.navbar ul {
  margin: 0;
}
.navbar li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline;
}
#holder {
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: #F7F4EE;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li><a class="active" href="home.html">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="news.html">News</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="holder">
  <header>""</header>
  <div id="body">""</div>
  <footer>""</footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Yea I'm not there yet sadly, but I'll sure use it when i star learning JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

To get navbar to top of the holder add `z-index` to navbar

```
#navbar {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: grey;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index:1;
}
```

For the dynamically set the `margin-top` to the holder you can add this jquery part

```
var navBarHeight = $('#navbar').height();

$('#holder').css({
    paddingTop:navBarHeight,
})
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/gwjkrzLb/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript to get the height of navbar

```
var navbarHeight = document.getElementById('navbar').offsetHeight;
```

and than put the value of the navbarHeight as the holder margin

```
document.getElementById('holder').style.height = navbarHeight + "px";
```